# Why isn't C# following my regex?

Tags: c#, regex

I have a C# application that reads a word file and looks for words wrapped in < brackets >

It's currently using the following code and the regex shown.

```
 private readonly Regex _regex = new Regex("([<])([^>]*)([>])", RegexOptions.Compiled);
```

I've used several online testing tools / friends to validate that the regex works, and my application proves this (For those playing at home, http://wordfiller.codeplex.com)!

My problem is however the regex will also pickup extra rubbish.

E.G

```
I'm walking on <sunshine>.
```

will return

```
sunshine>.
```

it should just return

```
<sunshine>
```

Anyone know why my application refuses to play by the rules?

Comment: Please show a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem. You've shown the regex but not the code using it. We don't need the full app, just a very short one which does nothing but show the problem.

Comment: I have noticed .NET doesn't play by the RegEx rules sometimes...The only thing I can think of is escaping the < to \<.

Comment: Ive run the regex `([<])([^>]*)([>])` and the string `I'm walking on <sunshine>.` through expresso and it matches `<sunshine>`.

Comment: Any reason why you'd use that regex instead of, say `(<[^>]*>)` or `<([^>]*)>` if you want to capture the word inside the brackets?

Comment: The folowing regex `\<([^>]*)\>` would be more efficient both brackets must be present for a match so there is no reason for them to be in groups. Also if you are looking for a word between brackets you should be using a `+` rather than a `*` giving you the following expression `\<([^>]+)\>`.

Comment: @Stevo: That's what my second program does in my answer too: `(<[^>]+>)`

Comment: @Code Monkey - Your program is matching excess characters that are not needed overcomplicating the whole thing!

Answer (score 5):

I don't think the problem is your regex at all. It could be improved somewhat -- you don't need the `([])` around each bracket -- but that shouldn't affect the results. **My strong suspicion is that the problem is in your C# implementation, not your regex.**

Your regex should split `<sunshine>` into three separate groups: `<`, `sunshine`, and `>`. Having tested it with the code below, that's exactly what it does. My suspicion is that, somewhere in the C# code, you're appending Group 3 to Group 2 without realizing it. Some quick C# experimentation supports this:

```
private readonly Regex _regex = new Regex("([<])([^>]*)([>])", RegexOptions.Compiled);
private string sunshine()
{
    string input = "I'm walking on <sunshine>.";
    var match = _regex.Match(input);
    var regex2 = new Regex("<[^>]*>", RegexOptions.Compiled); //A slightly simpler version

    string result = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < match.Groups.Count; i++)
    {
        result += string.Format("Group {0}: {1}\n", i, match.Groups[i].Value);
    }

    result += "\nWhat you're getting: " + match.Groups[2].Value + match.Groups[3].Value;
    result += "\nWhat you want: " + match.Groups[0].Value + " or " + match.Value;        
    result += "\nBut you don't need all those brackets and groups: " + regex2.Match(input).Value;

    return result;
}
```

#### Result:

```
Group 0: <sunshine>
Group 1: <
Group 2: sunshine
Group 3: >

What you're getting: sunshine>
What you want: <sunshine> or <sunshine> 
But you don't need all those brackets and groups: <sunshine>
```

Comment: Actually he is getting the period at the end as well (e.g. sunshine>.), not just sunshine>

Comment: I was just noticing that. But I can't tell for sure if that was part of his results, or if he intended it as punctuation in his question (unlikely, but possible). Either way, the problem must be in his C#. If he uses this code it should work properly.

Comment: oh, don't use Groups - Stevo3000 does not like them ;)

Answer (score 3):

We will need to see more code to solve the problem. There is an *off by one* error somewhere in your code. It is impossible for that regular expression to return `sunshine>.`. Therefore the regular expression in question is not the problem. I would assume, without more details, that something is getting the index into the string containing your match and it is one character too far into the string.

Answer (score 2):

If all you want is the text between < and > then you'd be better off using:

```
 [<]([^>]*)[>] or simpler: <([^>]+)>
```

If you want to include < and > then you could use:

```
 ([<][^>]*[>]) or simpler: (<[^>]+>)
```

You're expression currently has 3 Group Matches - indicated by the brackets ().

In the case of < sunshine> this will currently return the following:

> Group 1 : "<"
>
> Group 2 : "sunshine"
>
> Group 3 : ">"

So if you only looked at the 2nd group it should work!

The only explanation I can give for your observed behaviour is that where you pull the matches out, you are adding together Groups 2 + 3 and not Group 1.

Answer (score 1):

What you posted works perfectly fine.

```
        Regex _regex = new Regex("([<])([^>]*)([>])", RegexOptions.Compiled);
        string test = "I'm walking on <sunshine>.";
        var match = _regex.Match(test);
```

Match is `<sunshine>` i guess you need to provide more code.

Comment: Who is down voting these and why?

Comment: Well i agree that my answer wasn't really an answer, but the question was pretty unclear in the beginning, so my answer was sufficient for the question.

Comment: @dowhilefor: I agree. It's not your fault.

Comment: I believe that this is the answer, at least until the OP posts his code.

Comment: Agreed: this answer is as good as any here.  Whatever the problem is, it's in a part of the code the OP hasn't shown us.

Answer (score 0):

Regex is eager by default. Teach it to be lazy!

What I mean is, the * operator considers as many repetitions as possible (it's said to be eager). Use the *? operator instead, this tells Regex to consider as few repetitions as possible (i.e. to be lazy):

```
<.*?>
```

Comment: Greediness isn't the problem. `<.*?>` will do the exact same thing as `<[^>]*>`, because the `[^>]*` will stop matching as soon as it hits the `>` symbol.

Answer (score -1):

Because you are using parenthesis, you are creating matching groups. This is causing the match collection to match the groups created by the regular expression to also be matched. You can reduce your regular expression to `[<][^>]*[>]` and it will match only on the <text> that you wish.

Comment: Who is down voting these and why?

Comment: @Stevo3000 - I didn't downvote this, but it's probably because it's flat wrong. The parentheses split the brackets and content into three separate groups, so there's no way `([<])([^>]*)([>])` will turn `<sunshine>` into `sunshine>`. Also, why reduce it into `[<][^>]*[>]` when you can reduce it to `<[^>]*>`? That probably fueled the frustration here.

Comment: @Justin Morgan - Agreed, I was more pissed off with the down vote for dowhilefor's answer which is correct! I assumed that this was down voted by the same person.

Comment: The question lacks details and a lot of information in all the answers is pure speculation. I added a new answer, this one is wrong, and editing it doesn't really do any good since these comments have already been added, and would be taken out of context with the updated answer.

Comment: @Stevo3000 - Sometimes askers will -1 every answer that doesn't solve their problem, even when the issue isn't with the answer itself. Some people throw out downvotes when an answer isn't 100% perfect. I don't usually downvote unless it's deeply flawed (wrong, off-topic, etc).

Comment: @Charles: I agree. This hurt everyone.